# Next.Js oidc lib

Tags: next.js, openid-connect

I was searching but I could not find the solution. What would be the library of choice for accessing the authorization server, such as OpenIddict or Identity Server?
For instance, if you are to access Auth0 you would use nextjs-auth0 package, or in Blazor you would use AuthenticationMessageHandler, and so on.
These libraries handle the low level work, like sending the proper grant type, connection with authorize or token or other endpoints, crafting a request with proper code verifier, session id and so on, during the interaction with the authorization server.
Thank you.